# How to run a specific code from Google Colaboratory in Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: tensorflow, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

I am currently doing a Tensorflow course on Udacity. The code is executed there in Google Colaboratory.

Now I tryed to run the code locally on Jupyter Notebook. By doing this I get an error message.

The code is:

```py
    from __future__ import absolute_import, division, print_function, unicode_literals

    import os
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import numpy as np
```

```py
    import tensorflow as tf
    from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
```

```py
    import logging
    logger = tf.get_logger()
    logger.setLevel(logging.ERROR)
```

```py
    _URL = 'https://storage.googleapis.com/mledu-datasets/cats_and_dogs_filtered.zip'
    zip_dir = tf.keras.utils.get_file('cats_and_dogs_filterted.zip', origin=_URL, extract=True)
```

```py
    zip_dir_base = os.path.dirname(zip_dir)
    !find $zip_dir_base -type d -print
```

In Google Colaboratory it runs fine. On Jupyter Notebook I get after the last part the error message that it is the false date type.

What does the following line means?

```py
    !find $zip_dir_base -type d -print
```

What do I have to change to run it in Jupyter Notebook?

Answer (score 0):

You can check out this code from deep learning with python book. its the same datasets but it runs locally.
https://github.com/fchollet/deep-learning-with-python-notebooks/blob/master/5.2-using-convnets-with-small-datasets.ipynb